# np array shape for conv1d input

Tags: numpy, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a model with conv1d as the first layer.
My data is time series data where each sample consists of 41 time steps where each time step has 4 features.
I have about 1000 samples.
I have specified the input shape of the conve1d layer to be (41,4) as it supposed to be. 
However, I keep getting the following error: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_48: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2.

I suspect that the problem is that the shape of X is (1000,) while the shape of X[0] is (41,4). Has anyone encountered this problem?
Thanks.

```
l1=Input(shape=(41,4))
x=Conv1D(64,(4))(l1)
x=GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x)
x=Dense(1)(x)
model=Model(l1,x)
model.compile('rmsprop','binary_crossentropy',metrics=['acc'])
model.fit(X,y,32,10)
```

Comment: Do this: `l1 = Input(shape=(41, 4))`

Comment: I think it is the batch size, try Input(shape=(None,41,4))

Comment: @HaBom Doesn't work...

Comment: you should reshape the X to exactly (1000,41,4)

Answer (score 0):

You defined an expected input on your Conv1D to be be 2D -> (41, 4)
But you give to it an input of shape (41,), be consistant in your definitions !

If you specify the input_shape in your Conv1D layer, you don't need to feed an Input layer to it.
Or you can change the shape of this Input layer to be consistant with this input_shape.

Comment: I'm sorry I edited the code in the question. The problem is not with the input shape tuple. The problem is that my input data comes from a pandas dataframe column. The shape of the dataframe column values attribute (lets call it X) is (10000,). However, the shape of X[0] is (41,4). The model expects an input shape of (10000,41,4). Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: It's hard without having the data under the eyes, but can't you do 
->  X = df.values
in order to extract your data in the right format ? 
Or pre process your data in an other maner in order to have X.shape = (10000,41,4) before feeding it into your network